# check if matching query does not exist return empty string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

when i try to check if an object exist return it in excel file filed
if not return it an empty 'string' 
but i have error in the `if` sentence

```
pkg = Package.objects.get(pk=pk)
price_date_all = PackagePricesAndDates.objects.filter(package=pkg)

if price_date_all.get(territory=ter.pk).sales:
   list.append(str(price_date_all.get(territory=ter.pk).sales))
else :
   list.append('')
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Please format your code and also add the error stack you got.

Comment: @Austin PackagePricesAndDates matching query does not exist.
when the program loop to find sales for territory it says that does not exist

Comment: @Austin if does not exit, i want to return an empty string ''

Answer (score 0):

when you use `get` on a queryset, it will return either the record or raise a `DoesNotExist` exception.

```
try:
    list.append(str(price_date_all.get(territory=ter.pk).sales))
except DoesNotExist:
    list.append('')
```

FWIW, you should rename the `list` variable, because its already bound to the `list` builtin method for creating lists.  Don't reuse names that already exist